# How can i disable X-cart 5 Flexy template engine and use PHP?

Tags: php, template-engine, x-cart

Flexy is lack of documentation and maybe because of that I really don't like it at all. I want to use regular PHP in my module, is it possibly?
The best solution would be if I could use PHP just for my module, and do not apply it site-wide.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can defintely do it, though it is not recommended, by overriding **display()** method in each of your View classes.
The basic implementation is described in **\XLite\View\AView** class. You can override it in your View class to print in buffer the output of your custom php script like this:

```
public function display($template = null)
{
    include 'custom_php_template.php';
}
```

While having 'custom_php_template.php' with similar contents:

```
<?php
echo 'Hello world';
```

Please note that this is just the simple example and the real logic can be a lot more complex. Also, by using this approach you may need to create or adapt existing caching solution and other things by yourself.

Comment: Thank you! Your answer helped me find, I think, the right way. A did this:
in **getDefaultTemplate()** function I replace **return** from `$path.'body.tpl'` to `$path.'body.php'`.
Then I took **display()** function from **AView** class, commented out this line:
`$compiled = \XLite\Singletons::$handler->flexy->prepare($normalized);`
and change line from `include $compiled;` to `include $normalized;`.
For now it's look OK. Thank you again!

Comment: Great work, @shance! You took a step up from my example and did the right thing.